# Number of subsets of n is 2^n if n is even and 2^(n-1) when n is odd

Tags: math, combinatorics

I am not sure what is meant by number of subsets of 2^n please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

say I have:
s = {1,2,3,4} then 2^len(s) = 2^4 = 16

1. Then are the subsets the same length or varying lengths?
   [I can make 16 combinations when they are the same varying lengths]

   > ```
   > {0,
   >  {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}
   >  {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1,4}
   >  {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}
   >  {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4},
   >  {2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 4}
   >  {1, 2, 3, 4}
   > } = 16 elements
   > ```

What is confusing me is that:
there is an question in a book which ive read and says that if n is odd then the number of sub-sets are 2^(n - 1) however I am not sure how that can be correct unless my understanding of what these subsets are is incorrect.

Can someone please clarify how 2^(n-1) subsets if n is odd be true?

The question from the book is attached below

[image: Question]

Comment: Related/dup: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546414/what-is-the-proof-that-the-total-number-of-subsets-of-a-set-is-2n

Comment: It's not true, so it would be hard to clarify! I guess you misread/misinterpreted something (or the book is wrong itself, less likely)

Comment: I am quite sure that this statement must have some additional context. By itself, applying it to a general set of numbers, it's wrong. If you have an addition, e.g. , that for odd-n sets the first number of the set has to be included in all subsets then it will be true...

Comment: okay ill clarify the question

Comment: I think that the intended reading is "Prove that the number of (subsets that have an odd number of elements) of `[n]` is `2^(n-1)`" I.e it's the subsets that have an odd number of elements, not the original set.

Comment: Ohhh thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misreading the problem.  The problem says to find the number of subsets that have an odd number of elements.  This doesn't involve the parity of the original set.